# Stop .exe in command window from restarting computer after uninstall

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-installer

I am uninstalling a Cisco Agent Desktop maintenance update from several thousand client machines and I'm unable to stop it from restarting. An MSI file is calling an `srRollbackRepair.exe` file that runs in a blank CMD window, and after about 10 seconds it restarts the computer.

The `srRollbackRepair` is not needed because it is attempting to repair the original installation, which will also be removed (or may already be removed), so there is no point to a rollback repair. If I remove the original application (without the maintenance update) it leaves the update.

Is there a way for me to set some sort of flag/switch that either

1. stops the `.exe` from being called by the MSI or
2. prevents the `srRollbackRepair.exe` from generating a restart or
3. autocloses the cmd window before it can complete and restart since rollback is not necessary?

Maybe there is a way to autoclose the cmd window after a few miliseconds? I know the `.exe` is starting the restart because I can run it independent of the MSI and it restarts.

Also I know the MSI doesn't need the `.exe` file to complete uninstallation because if I exit its cmd window after it launches it will never restart – and under Programs and Features, the maintenance package is gone.

I have already tried the following on the `.exe` and MSI:

```
/? (generates nothing for exe)
REBOOT=REALLYSUPRESS
/noreboot
/norestart
/delayrestart
```

Comment: Can you just remove the exe from the uninstaller or replace it with a dummy exe that does nothing?

Comment: Did you try /promptrestart?

Comment: I actually fixed this about ten minutes after I asked it but stackoverflow wont let me answer my own question. I deleted the whole CAD folder in Common Files which contained the exe and it didn't call the exe or give an error, which worked. So yeah, Ganesh, you would have been right.

Comment: WHY are you crossposting the same question on >1 SE?  This is very bad, please discontinue this practice.

Comment: mdpc, I don't understand what you're saying. I have only posted this here

Comment: You said "Stack Overflow" wouldn't let you post an answer, but [so] is a different site. This here is Super User. Maybe that's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: *Super User. My bad. It's owned by StackOverflow and I'm an ex programmer so I forgot

Answer (score 0):

[InstallShield with MSI command line](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q105473&sliceId=)

record uninstall ISS answer file:

```
setup.exe /uninst /r /f1"<ISS_Files_Directory>\uninstall.iss"
```

silent uninstall use ISS answer file:

```
setup.exe /uninst /s /f1"<ISS_Files_Directory>\uninstall.iss"
```

may be help ...

way 2, [Privilege Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716%28VS.85%29.aspx):

1. Disable privilege SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME.
2. Uninstall MSI.
3. Enable privilege SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your script rename or delete srRollbackRepair.exe first.  This is what my file looks like:

```
del /f /q "{path-to-the-file}\srRollbackRepair.exe" 
#uninstall service release
msiexec.exe /qn /x{4682F8A7-0BA1-4165-A003-EC50BB43A8AF} /norestart
#uninstall CAD
MsiExec.exe /qn /x{007C5E6D-3037-4C00-A5FD-561F239169C4} /norestart
```

Verify the install codes are correct for your version but otherwise you should be good. I used this to remove CAD then install a newer version.